# How to view Response ReasonPhrase

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Developer tool on Chrome as well postman don't show reason phrase of Response message. ReasonPhrase doesn't show either in response body or in response header. how to view it.

Comment: You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see if you are actually getting data in the response or an error.  The status of a good response is 200 DONE.

Comment: statusText shows value of ReasonPhrase.

Comment: Does sniffer show more than one request/response?  The response in c# will have an OuterText (and OuterHTML) and you need to parse the response or put into a html viewer (like a web browser control).